# merge tif images using image.merge

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to merge 4 tifs together to form a CMYK image.

This is the code that I have so far:-

```
import Image

m = "C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\magnew.tif"
c = "C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\cyannew.tif"
y = "C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\yellownew.tif"
k = "C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\knew.tif"

im = Image.merge("CMYK",(c,m,y,k))

im.save("C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\AAA.tif")
```

This gives me an error when run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\try5.py", line 18, in <module>
    im = Image.merge("CMYK",(c,m,y,k))
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1996, in merge
    if im.mode != getmodetype(mode):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`m`, `c`, `y` and `k` need to be `PIL` `Image` objects so for instance

```
m = Image.open("C:\Documents and Settings\dbigwood\Desktop\TEST\magnew.tif")
```